# SQL make subquery of two sparate query

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT max( `reg_date` ) AS endtime, min( `reg_date` ) AS starttime, sum( `distance` ) AS total FROM `user_distance` WHERE user_id =8 GROUP BY CAST( `reg_date` AS DATE )";

$sql1="SELECT CAST( `reg_date` AS DATE ) AS date, count( * ) AS customer_total FROM `customer` WHERE user_id =8 GROUP BY CAST( `reg_date` AS DATE )";
```

I am getting perfect result for this two queries, but I want to combine the results of this two queries.

Comment: using union with in a single query and make blank for extra column to avoid column mismatch error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop temporary table if exist temp1;
create temporary table temp1
SELECT max( `reg_date` ) AS endtime, min( `reg_date` ) AS starttime, sum( `distance` ) AS total 
FROM `user_distance` 
WHERE user_id =8 GROUP BY CAST( `reg_date` AS DATE )"

union 

SELECT CAST( `reg_date` AS DATE ) AS date,''as starttime, count( * ) AS customer_total 
FROM `customer` 
WHERE user_id =8 GROUP BY CAST( `reg_date` AS DATE )";

select * from temp1;
```